# event for slider in apache cordova

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating an app with cordova. I have a problem, 
I can not find the function that it is used when using the slider

```
<label for="slider-fill" class="ou">Ora 23:00</label>
<input class="ou" type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill23" value="5" min="5" max="30" data-highlight="true">
```

Comment: which _slider_? is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519349/4845566) what you want?

Comment: i want slidestop