# How to listen to input type range with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load some data via ajax upon user interaction from changing a jquery mobile range min/max slider.

```
<label for="filter_price">Preis:</label>
   <div data-role="rangeslider" id="filter_price" style="touch-action: none;">
   <input type="range" name="price_from" id="price_from" min="1" max="2000" value="1" data-popup-enabled="true" class="filter_watch">
    <input type="range" name="price_to" id="price_to" min="1" max="20000" value="20000" data-popup-enabled="true" class="filter_watch">
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#price_from').on("change mousemove", function 
 () {
   alert('price filter'); 
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/28avj4x5/

On jsfiddle every mouse move triggers the alert, while only the chagne should trigger. On my project the event does not fire at all. I also tried `change.(function...` without any effect.

How can I trigger the event upon changing value and releasing the button (the way the ajax call only fires when the user stops interacting)?

Comment: Try using `keyup` event instead of `change`

Comment: is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/ynf8cLx1/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Where do I see the console on jsfiddle?. Does not seem to have any effect, also keyup did not work neither: $('#price_from').on("keyup", function (e) {

Comment: in the fiddle hit F12 and click on console. but you can just change it to alert if you want

Comment: OK, seems to work in your exmpl. On my project it does not, same code?! Have a look with a mobile device: http://staging.www.de.watchgurus.de/rolex/  andy:newpw2 Click on filter in the header and select a price range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `slidestop` event twas designed specifically for this purpose:

```
$(document).on("slidecreate", "#price_from", function(e) {
  $(this).on("slidestop", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    // pass val to the ajax call
  });
});
```

Try it out in my code snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519349/4845566

Comment: Thank you, I see that it is working in your example. Something must be wrong in my environment as neither of those events fire for the slider. Please have a look: http://staging.www.de.watchgurus.de/omega/ andy:newpw2 Click on "filter" in the header and change the price. The js code is here: http://staging.static.watchgurus.de/MEW/subapp_search/app_local/act_functions_search_v1.1.2.min.js

Comment: I see. You can't use `$( document ).ready` because the JQM widgets are instanced somewhat later, during `page` initialization. You should hook the slider callbacks inside the `pagecreate` handler. These events aren't *delegatable*-

Comment: I can not really follow what you are suggesting. Could you make an example. Where is the pagecreate handler?

Comment: @merlin: added an example using the `slidecreate` event (forget the `pagecreate` for now).

Comment: You are a geinious! May I ask why this was neccesary and how you fixed that? It might be related to the fact that I can not change the min/max values as well. The event is firing now, but the following command has no effect: $('#price_to').slider("option", "max", obj.stats.price_max);

Comment: @merlin Glad this helped You! Regarding the question inside Your last comment, I am sorry but I can't understand with such a short description. Please, feel free to post a new question with a full explanation. Will do my best, but here at SO there are a lot of great people which can help You. Regarding JQM events, here is the full story: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)